# xConnect Instances need to be Anonymous or Windows authentication?

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

We installed xConnect, Marketing Automation and Reference Data instances in a scaled Sitecore 9.0.1 environment. While accessing the URLs it is asking for the credentials cause the corresponding IIS instances are installed with windows authentication OOTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIF *shoudln't* be installing the instances with any special authentication.

Anonymous is what is required.

I wonder if the IIS defaults have been modified such that it creates a site with authentication?